# Accessing Summernote inside an iframe from the parent document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, summernote

How do you use jQuery to access an instance inside an iframe from the container document?

I'm rendering a [Summernote](https://summernote.org/) widget inside an iframe, and it works well, but I need to add some logic to enable and disable it from the parent document.

Without the iframe, doing this is as simple as:

```
$('#mysummernoteid').summernote('disable')
$('#mysummernoteid').summernote('enable')
```

However, now that it's inside an iframe, I'm no longer able to access the `.summernote()` method.

I thought you could access iframe contents with jQuery via:

```
$('#iframeid').contents().find('#mysummernoteid')
```

and that does indeed retrieve the correct `<div>` I'm using for summernote in my iframe. However, if I then try to access `.summernote()` my browser gives me the error:

```
.summernote is not a function
```

What's even more odd is that if I inspect the object returned by `$('#iframeid').contents().find('#mysummernoteid')` in the browser console, I can see the summernote instance registered at `jQuery331057949734821731762/summernote` in the object tree.

What's going on here? Why isn't jQuery able to access instances bound to objects in an iframe, even though the console can see them, and how do I fix it?